# CS1061 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method

Tags: c#, sql, csv, import

Hi im getting the Error CS1061  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Text' and no extension method 'Text' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

No matter what i do i cannot seem to get rid of this error. Im trying to make the csv file importable to my SQL DB.

Comment: `.Text` is usually a property on say, a [TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.text(v=vs.110).aspx). As far as I can tell you just need a string. Change to, `private string txtFileName;`, and replace all `txtFileName.Text` with `txtFileName`.

Comment: The vast majority of the time that you see `object`, `dynamic` or `ArrayList` in C#, the author is *doing it wrong*. This isn't Java.

Comment: You've provided 170 lines of code with no indication where the problem is. Please reduce this to a [mcve].

Comment: The problem is that `private object txtFileName;` declared txtFileName as an `object` which doesn't have anything named `Text` associated with it. Unless you provide more information about what you are trying to do with it, that's about all I can say on the matter.

Comment: Thank you, this issue is now fixed 

".Text is usually a property on say, a TextBox. As far as I can tell you just need a string. Change to, private string txtFileName;, and replace all txtFileName.Text with txtFileName."

Fixed the issue. However, the form does not show any data when debugged. The form does open and there are no errors.